# Python: Compare elements in two list by pair

Tags: python, list, compare

I am so sorry for asking so silly question.
So I have got two lists(columns) for instance:

```
In:
a= [0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]
b= [1.0,2.0,3.0,5.0,6.0]
zp = list(zip(a,b)) #And I zipped it for better view.
for i in zp:
    print (i)

Out:
(0.0, 1.0)
(1.0, 2.0)
(2.0, 3.0)
(3.0, 5.0)
(4.0, 6.0)
```

I would like compare each i[1] with each i[0] in the next pair(tuple)
For example:

```
1st pair i[1] = 1.0 compare with i[0] in 2nd
2nd pair i[0] = 1.0 compare with i[0] in 3rd
etc
```

I would like find difference in pair.

```
If i[1] != i[0] 
  print this value 

Answer is 5.0 & 4.0
```

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial zip for better view is not completely necessary.

You could simply `zip` a slice of `a` starting from index 1 with `b`, and then compare the items using a `for` loop:

```
a = [0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]
b = [1.0,2.0,3.0,5.0,6.0]

for i, j in zip(a[1:], b):
    if i != j:
        print(j, i)
#            5.0, 4.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That looks great. But can you explain why you did not slice list `b[:-1]`?

Comment: Thank you very much! That looks great. But can you explain why you did not slice list `b[:-1]`?

Comment: Ah yes, `zip` stops at the shortest iterable, so `b[:-1]` will be redundant as the last item of `b` will never reached due to the shorter length of `a`

Comment: It can sound strange but I wonder what if I 'filter' list for `None`. In my case in the list `a` zero will be gone. So I insted of  `for i, j in zip(a[1:], b):` I should use simple `for i, j in zip(a, b):` because I have `a[0]=None` and length of `a` shorter now, doen't it?

Comment: That would work, but unnecessarily longer. Is there any reason you're trying to avoid slicing `a`?

Comment: hah)  I would rather prefer using slicing. But I have got xrls file, and some cell are empty and the first cell is always starts with zero I avoid emtpy cells usining `filter`. If I use this code with slicing obviously I will get wrong result because I deleted first value(zero) and all other emty cells. Actually I don't know why python think that zero number and `None` are the same

Comment: 0 and `None` are both *falsy*, `filter` removes all falsy values when you pass the predicate as `None`. To ensure you are only filtering out 0, you can use a lambda in your filter instead of `None`:  `lambda x: x != 0.0`. But I think you can leave out filtering since you're going to slice the list later on.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. but it is complicated. When I am filltering out  zero, script gives wrong result because it counts empty. for instance when I am using `a = list(filter(None, colA))
b = list(filter(None, colB)) for i, j in zip(a, b):` Script works well, but when I try `lambda x: x != 0.0` or `if not x is None` result looks strange. It compares from value to epmty cell etc

Comment: What I did: 
`a = list(filter(None, colA))
b = list(filter(None, colB))
cell=sh.cell(3,0)
s= cell.value
if s ==0:
    for i, j in zip(a, b):
        if i != j:
            print(j, i)
    else:
        print("OK")
elif s !=0:
    for i, j in zip(a[1:], b):
        if i != j:
            print(j, i)
    else:
        print("OK")` what do you think?

Comment: Code is hard to read in comments :) If that works you may keep it that way. If you run into any problems, do not hesitate ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

index variant without zip and enumerate

```
a = [0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]
b = [1.0,2.0,3.0,5.0,6.0]

for i in a:
    if a.index(i) and i != b[a.index(i)-1]:
       print "{0} > {1}".format(i, b[a.index(i)-1])
```

Comment: Please perform your code by a little bit change of `a` and `b` as: `a = [0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0, 8.0]`, 
`b = [1.0,2.0,3.0,5.0,6.0, 6.0]`

Comment: works and same res like @moses section with zip (incl. your new list), can you perform the code please with your changes

Comment: It gives a result like `4.0>5.0`!!

Comment: sry, i cant follow you, ">" its a string char

Comment: I was wondering if  ">"('greater than')  is just comparing. It's literally saying the value of left operand is greater than the value of right operand In a wrong way.